# Android Room Database - Designing Database to handle both Sync and Async Queries

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I'm new to Android programming and even newer to working with Room database. I already did some reading on the Android architecture components for Room and also followed some tutorials for creating a simple working Room database.

One really good example I found is this: https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-7-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-15-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/15-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel/15-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel.html.

I also briefly read some other tutorials found online. Some things I've learned is that normal @Insert and @Delete annotated operations are automatically handled by Room, but as for any @Query annotated operations, I need to make sure to call them asynchronously to avoid locking the main UI thread.

Many example covers LiveData and how you can use simple @Insert and @Delete asynchronously and any changes are observed by LiveData and the ArrayAdaptor that uses any data wrapped by LiveData show the updated information.

I'm currently working with an App for inventorying books.
In the main activity, I want to show user a list of all books and the above approach works well. I'd create a query as shown below and then observe any changes and allow the ListView to change automaticaly as the table is updated.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM book")
public LiveData<List<Book>> findAllBooks();
```

But how do I asynchronously handle other @Query operations such as the following, get the results and as soon as they are available, and then show them to the user?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM book where category = :category")
public List<Book> getBookByCatetory(String category);
```

When user wants to filter a master list of books by category, I want my App to run the above query and get all books with the specified category and then display the read-only list to the user in another activity. It shouldn't require any observer. This sounds like it should be a synchronous operation, but such process is discouraged because it may lock the UI thread.

What is the best design to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532832/read-and-write-room-database-synchronically-everywhere

Comment: @mhinton link is not working above.

Comment: @nnyerges link says "page is not found"